# Python shared object module naming convention

Tags: python, module, naming-conventions, shared-libraries

I have written a Python module in C++ and built it as a shared object library and it worked fine.  But while figuring all that out, I noticed (via strace) that Python looks for a few different variations `import` is called.  In particular, when I say `import foo`, Python searches for, in order:

- foo (a directory)
- foo.so
- foomodule.so
- foo.py
- foo.pyc

This was all pretty understandable except for foomodule.so.  Why does Python look for everything both as name.so and namemodule.so?  Is it some historical artifact?  I searched quite a bit and came up with no explanation at all, and am left wondering if I should name my module foomodule.so instead of foo.so.  My system seems to have some existing Python modules following each convention, so I can't help but wonder if the different names imply something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is actually platform-dependent, Python has different suffixes that it tries depending on the operating system. Here is the initialization of the suffix table in `import.c`:

```
#ifdef HAVE_DYNAMIC_LOADING
    memcpy(filetab, _PyImport_DynLoadFiletab,
           countD * sizeof(struct filedescr));
#endif
    memcpy(filetab + countD, _PyImport_StandardFiletab,
           countS * sizeof(struct filedescr));
    filetab[countD + countS].suffix = NULL;

    _PyImport_Filetab = filetab;
```

So it joins two lists, `_PyImport_DynLoadFiletab` and `_PyImport_StandardFiletab`. The latter is the easier one, it is defined as `[".py", ".pyw", ".pyc"]` in the same file (second entry is only present on Windows). `_PyImport_DynLoadFiletab` is defined in various `dynload_<platform>.c` files. On Unix-based systems its value is `[".so", "module.so"]`, for CygWin it defines `[".dll", "module.dll"]` whereas for OS/2 it is `[".pyd", ".dll"]` and for Windows it is simply `[".pyd"]`.

<del>I went through the source code history and finally arrived at this change from 1999 that apparently added "module.so" as a possible suffix: http://hg.python.org/cpython-fullhistory/diff/8efa37a770c6/Python/importdl.c. So the changes were originally added for NeXTStep (the one that eventually became Mac OS X), for particular linking settings only. I don't know this OS so it is hard to tell why it was done - I suspect that it was simply to prevent naming conflicts. E.g. a framework library `foo.so` might be loaded already and the OS won't allow loading another library with the same name. So `foomodule.so` was a compromise to allow a Python module with the name `foo` to exist nevertheless.</del>

**Edit**: The paragraph above was wrong - I didn't go far enough back in history, thanks to senderle for pointing that out. In fact, the interesting change appears to be http://hg.python.org/cpython-fullhistory/diff/2230/Python/import.c from 1994 which is where a new module naming scheme (`foo.so`) was added as an alternative to the old scheme (`foomodule.so`). I guess that the old form became deprecated at some point given that support for it has been removed for some platforms like Windows in one of the numerous rewrites of that code. Note that even when it was first introduced the short module name version was listed first - meaning that it already was the preferred variant.

**Edit2**: I searched the mailing list/newsgroup from 1994 to see whether this change was discussed somewhere - it doesn't look like it was, Guido van Rossum seems to have implemented it without telling anyone.

Comment: interesting, I didn't know about that full-history browser. There's some deep institutional memory in there. However, the definition `#define LONG_EXT "module.so"` -- if that's what you're referring to -- was there long before the patch you're talking about. In fact, it was there when [`importdl.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython-fullhistory/file/d7e91437f0a2/Python/importdl.c) was first created!

Comment: @senderle: Thank you, I indeed made a mistake. `importdl.c` was created in a rewrite, the original code can be found in `import.c` - I found the change that introduced two naming schemes and updated my answer. Too bad that Pythons institutional memory doesn't include discussions that led to a change.

Answer (score 10):

This is merely a guess, but I can only assume this is related to the below, from [Extending Python with C or C++](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#extending-python-with-c-or-c).

> Begin by creating a file spammodule.c. (Historically, if a module is called spam, the C file containing its implementation is called spammodule.c; if the module name is very long, like spammify, the module name can be just spammify.c.)

I suppose this convention extends to the name of the `.so` file. That conjecture is further supported by section 1.5 of [the same](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#compilation-and-linkage).

---

Based on Wladimir's [excellent discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319379/python-shared-object-module-naming-convention/6531558#6531558), I've found the [first reference](http://hg.python.org/cpython-fullhistory/rev/e149c77d173c?revcount=1280) to `module.so` as a suffix. It's from a patch to support dynamic loading of SunOS libraries, from "Bill." ([Bill Jansson?](http://www.python.org/search/hypermail/python-1994q3/0082.html)) Clearly the `module`-as-suffix convention began before the use of `.so` shared libraries, and when `.so` libraries were adopted, the convention was simply maintained.

I think Wladimir is right though -- the interesting change is the one in which the short module name convention was adopted. That confirms my guess that the long module name was the earlier convention.

Comment: I went back and checked the order in which Python looks for the various files.  I note that it looks for foo.so before foomodule.so, which seems weird if foomodule.so is the preferred form.  I will wait for others to chime in, because while I find your answer reasonable, it's also a bit hand-wavy (no offense, I guess I'm still looking for some source to say "this is why we have two patterns" or something like that).

Comment: Yeah, there's no doubt that it's hand-wavy :). But it seems clear to me that there must have been an early `foomodule` convention that is no longer preferred, but that would be hard to exorcise for some reason. I'd also be interested to hear from the old guard about this question.

Comment: Even before `module.so` was added Python already loaded modules with `module.o` file name suffix - the change you linked to merely added support for SunOS. The patch that added support for dynamic loading was http://hg.python.org/cpython-fullhistory/diff/609/Python/import.c and it already uses `module.o` as a suffix - I guess that's following Amoeba's naming convention.

Comment: @Wladimir, yes, exactly -- that's why I said "`.so` shared libraries" and not "shared libraries" in general. Furthermore, I'm quite certain that `module.o` was the conventional suffix long before any form of dynamic loading was adopted. I suppose we could confirm that by looking at makefiles!