# What is the precedence of python compiled files in imports?

Tags: python, compilation, bytecode, cython

Python files are compiled to bytecode (*.pyc).

Using Cython you can compile them to machine code (*.so in Linux).

If you use have both files in the same folder, under the same name what is the precedence between them?

Is there an automatic way to ensure that the *.so file is used instead of the *.pyc one? Or you have to do it explicitly  in the code (renaming etc)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python will load the `.so` file first. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6319379/577088) for an ordered list of the suffixes that python searches for.

Well, I'll just tell you:

```
foo (a directory)
foo.so
foomodule.so
foo.py
foo.pyc
```