# Can you compile a .py file with cython instead of a pyx file?

Tags: python, cython

I have a file foo.py, and it contains a very slow function that takes 8 minutes to compute. However, when I change the file to `foo.pyx` and compile it with cython with no other changes, it takes 5 minutes to compute.

My question is: if I run `cython foo.py` instead of `cython foo.pyx` and then run 
`gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o foo.so foo.c`

When I run `import foo`, will python import the `.py` file or the compiled `.so` file? 
Does the pyx really need to be there, and is there a way to force it to take the `.so` over the `.py` if it exists?

The reason for this is that I cannot change the name of foo.py without breaking code on other people's machines, but I'd really like it to be faster for my tests cases. It would be great if I could just compile it locally without worrying about breaking code elsewhere.

(I'm testing this as we speak, but its taking awhile)

Comment: Quick look into the manual explains your questions: http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html

Comment: this doesnt answer the question. My question is will the python interpreter take a .py file over a .so file if it exists? Because I dont want to change the name from foo.py to foo.pyx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried it on Windows with some Cython code I have been working with recently. The compiled module takes precedence.
This was also confirmed in both of the following questions:

[What is the precedence of python compiled files in imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584457/what-is-the-precedence-of-python-compiled-files-in-imports)

[Python shared object module naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319379/python-shared-object-module-naming-convention)