# Compling Python Package via Cython

Tags: python, cython, importerror, python-packaging, cythonize

i am fairly new to cython, does anyone know how to compile a python project via Cython (with relative low overhead), since I keep getting the following import error:

> ImportError: No module named CythonRelated.testSource.MyClassObject

My test project structure is like this:

```
CythonRelated/
           setup.py
           testSource/
                  MainCythonTest.py
                  MyClassObject.py
                  MainCythonTest.pyx   
                  MyClassObject.pyx
```

Where MainCythonTest imports class from MyClassObject module ( via

`from CythonRelated.testSource.MyClassObject import myCustomObj`

), initializes an object and calls an object method.

My setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(
    name = "My cython test app",
    ext_modules = cythonize("testSource/*.pyx", include_path = ["."]),
    packages = ["CythonRelated", "CythonRelated.testSource"]
)
```

What am I missing?

Taking setup.py outside CythonRelated (and obviously updating the corresponding path of *.pyx files in cythonize) didn't help either

> MyClassObject.py

```
import sys
print sys.version_info

class myCustomObj():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value_ = value

    def classInfo(self):
        print "calling class {0} object with value of  {1}".format(self.__class__.__name__,
                                                                  self.value_)
```

> MainCythonTest.py

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()

from CythonRelated.testSource.MyClassObject import myCustomObj

def myFunc():

    aObj = myCustomObj(12)

    bObj = myCustomObj(21)

    bObj.classInfo()

    aObj.classInfo()

    print "myFunc called"

myFunc()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `setup.py` file anyway, as it cannot be part of a project that it "compiles".

Then, the main issue is that you lack `__init__.py` files in `CythonRelated` and `CythonRelated/testSource`. Without this file, the directory is not an importable Python module. With these two changes, I could `pip install --user -e .` the package and also run the program `MainCythonTest.py`

Comment: Thanks - but then it seems that python does not take the compiled versions. Try removing the .py files and installing only with .pyx, it is not able to find the modules when you start importing them (although the install goes without errors) Or do you always need to keep the .py files? How can you be sure that it is taking the compiled version then? I saw this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584457/what-is-the-precedence-of-python-compiled-files-in-imports but anyhow ...

Comment: Ok, I didn't catch this. I just copied the content for the `.pyx` file. When you are "cythonizing" a `.py` file, there is no need for the `.py` file to remain. You can simply remove it.