# What does 'ml' stand for in PyMethodDef?

Tags: python, python-internals

The PyMethodDef C struct has several fields that are prefixed with 'ml'. What does 'ml' stand for?

https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/structures.html#c.PyMethodDef

Comment: Maybe it is an abbreviation for "model".  After all, `PyMethodDef` is a model for method definitions.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of googling, I found [another stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678174/how-does-module-loading-work-in-cpython) that indirectly answered your question.

That is, the `ml` stands for **M**odular **L**oading.

[Some people](http://xmipp.cnb.csic.es/twiki/bin/view/Xmipp/XmippBindings) even break this down further to just **m**odu**l**e, as in `module_method`.

The whole answer to the link stack question is definitely worth the read, too!

Comment: I too am fond of both the question and the answer to which you link! ;-) That said, I'm not sure this is the right answer. The PyMethodDef struct can be used for *statically* linked modules.

Comment: Haha I just realized that too was your question! This is comical given how much time i spent hunting for that answer...

Comment: It's even your answer :0