# Python import modules from other packages

Tags: python, module, path, bash

Python will by default be looking for modules from `lib/python2.7/site-packages`
But I'm now trying to import packages from other directories on HPCC, which I have to rely on, because I've no root access, it'll be difficult to install myself.

But my question is: how to import modules from other directories?

I've tried:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/import/modules:$PYTHONPATH"
```

But it's not working.
What should I do?
Thanks

=========================================

[image]

My python to use is `2.7.9` ,so I've already set in `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/share/pkg/python/2.7.9/bin:$PATH"
```

`2.7.9_packages` is the directories containing modules(you could see those folders) I want:

[image]

but you could see `2.7.9_packages` and `2.7.9` are under the same path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing user defined modules in python from a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516579/importing-user-defined-modules-in-python-from-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Where to place your own modules:-

1. Place your modules in one of the directories that python normally searches
2. Place all modules in same directory as your program
3. Create a directory/directories that will hold your modules and modify `sys.path`

I am sure the third option is exactly what your looking for

You can modify sys.path in various ways

- Hardcode PYTHONPATH environment variable in your program code
- Using .pth method

  Create a new file eg `myModules.pth` and place it in path specified by `sys.prefix` on windows the content of `myModules.pth` can be

  c:\My Documents\python\modules

That means you can place your path for that specific module you want to import there

Comment: I'm still very confused that, say, I'd like to import "numpy", but under "numpy", there's "bin" and "lib"; so my path will include to "bin" or "lib"?