# ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package python

Tags: python, importerror

I have a directory structure like this.

```
Chatbot/
   utils/
     abc.py
   projects/
      proj1/
        utils/
          __init__.py
          data_process.py
        components/
          class1.py
```

I have two `utils` folders in my structure, one at the top level and one inside my projects folder.

Now I want to import `data_process.py` file inside `class1.py`. So I tried like this

```
from utils.data_process import DataProcess
```

but it is referencing the top-level `utils` folder and even VSCode is not recognizing it. I tried creating `__init__.py` file inside the `utils` folder but still did not work.

I tried with empty `__init__.py` and then placing this content

```
from . import data_process
__all__ = ['data_proces']
```

then

```
from .data_process import DataPreprocess
__all__ = ['DataPreprocess']
```

then I tried

```
from ..utils.data_process import DataProcess
```

VSCode is recognizing this but it is not working and throws the error

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Even I tried changing the name utils to some other name but still the same issue

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

A python module is defined by a special file called `__init__.py` and this file should be present in all the subdirectories. So, your file structure would be:

```
Chatbot/
   __init__.py
   utils/
     __init__.py
     abc.py
   projects/
      __init__.py
      proj1/
        __init__.py
        utils/
          __init__.py
          data_process.py
        components/
          __init__.py
          class1.py
          class2.py
```

Now, you can do a relative import like:

- Use `.` for importing something within the same directory. Example:

```py
# file Chatbot/projects/proj1/components/class2.py
from .class1 import *
```

- Similarly, use `..` for two-level, and `...` for three-level, and so on!

For instance:

```py
# file Chatbot/projects/proj1/components/class2.py
from ..utils.data_process import * # import from data_process.py
# there will be four "." earlier I made a counting mistake
from ....utils.abc import * # import something from abc.py
```

### Coding Convention

When writing a python module/package, you might want to follow [PEP8 Convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Moreover, I believe you are trying to do different projects using your package `Chatbot`, is that correct? Then, it is a good practice that you set `PYTHONPATH` for `Chatbot` and do all the projects, and imports seperately.

### EDIT: Uploading Dummy File

I'm able to work on this project seamlessly even with using two `utils` directories. Project Structure:

[image]

`main` file and its output:

```py
# file main.py
from chatbot.utils.abc import hello as a1
from chatbot.projects.proj1.components.class1 import super_hello
from chatbot.projects.proj1.utils.data_process import hello as b1

print(a1(), b1())
print(super_hello())
```

[image]

Similarly, if you have `chatbot` under `PYTHONPATH` you can call the project from anywhere from your device.

Code details and files are [added into my github account](https://github.com/ZenithClown/SO-68554755) for details.

Comment: chatbot outer project use the model created from inner project, thats why it contains projects folder.. projects folder contains the independent project but its output is used on top level chatbot project.

Comment: and do i need to mention PYTHONPTH in env variable?

Comment: and i need to add init.py file to every folder, that are not even packages?

Comment: I don't understand by outer/inner project that you have mentioned. You might want to look into these to clear concepts: Python Packaging - [[1](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), [2](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-package)]; Import UD Package - [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516579), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RuMJ53CKds&ab_channel=Telusko)]

Comment: outer project is chatbot and inner project chatbot/projects/proj1

Comment: Technically, you should [modularize python code](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_modules_and_modular_programming.php) when you want to group similar functions. Does this outer and inner project is related? If yes, then you might want to combine them.

Comment: If you are creating a `chatbot` and you want to use this **python package** in different codes, then this should not be the way you design the code. Instead you should use `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` mentioned by @SorousH Bakhtiary

Answer (score 1):

`sys.path` is where Python searches to find modules and packages and It does it **in order**.

So you can put `...../proj1/` at the beginning of the list, when python start searching it will find the `utils` folder in that path first !

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r'...../proj1/')
```

But this cause another problem, python always find `utils` in that folder first, that's not what you want.

### solution number 1

Absolute import:

```
from Chatbot.projects.proj1.utils.data_process import DataProcess
```

### solution number 2

use relative imports which is mentioned by @Mr.Hobo.

Comment: Yes, `sys.path` method is good.. but it is tedious to mention each time... you can get over this using the `PYTHONPATH` [tutorial in windows](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pythonpath-environment-variable-in-python/)

Comment: @Mr.Hobo emm In fact both of them(PYTHONPATH or sys.path) are causing problems. The main issue is we have two names called `utils` ! whichever path is accessible first in sys.path, that `utils` will be encountered first it doesn't matter where we are.  So better solution is using absolute import as I mentioned.

Comment: please check the updated answer. I was able to do the project with ease w/o any problem. I have also added a link to my personal GitHub project account related to this project structure.

Comment: @Mr.Hobo I've updated my answer and referenced to yours for relative imports.