# ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, importerror, python-module

File Structure:

[image]

routers/blog.py file

```py
from ..Blog import schema, models
```

I am in routers/blog.py file. I want to import `schema` and `models` files. But I am getting this error.

```
from ..Blog import schema, models
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I was following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554755/valueerror-attempted-relative-import-beyond-top-level-package-python), but still unable to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI: " ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70874423/fastapi-importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080756/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647164/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342222/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to get rid of `..Blog`. The following should work:

```py
import schema, models
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `PYTHONPATH` in your environment, then run the FastAPI application in terminal.
For example if your root project directory is under your home, like:
`/home/tashifa/Blog`:
The `export` command be like:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH=/home/tashifa/Blog:$PYTHONPATH
```

After that, your imports in `blog.py` be like:

```py
from routers import schemas, models
```