# How to get path of the pyd file aka equivalent of __file__

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I have a file `package.py` that i am trying to package into  `package.pyd`. I have the following statement in `package.py`

```
    CURR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

which works fine when I run `package.py` but when I import `package.pyd` into another file `wrapper.py` I get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\Wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package
  File "package.py", line 40, in init package (package.c:4411)
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

How can I get the location of the .pyd file. Also is there a way to check if it is being run as a .pyd or .py.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [__file__ variable not available in module init](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1035).
But you can get `__file__` after module was loaded:

```
def get_file():
    return __file__
```

You can check the `__file__` variable to know what file was loaded.
Also keep in mind python's search order: `pyd (so), py, pyw(for windows), pyc`.

More information about it is in this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319379/python-shared-object-module-naming-convention)

Found two working methods.

1. Involving [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module:

   ```
   import inspect
   import sys
   import os

   if hasattr(sys.modules[__name__], '__file__'):
       _file_name = __file__
   else:
       _file_name = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())

   CURR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(_file_name))
   ```
2. `import` some file from the same level and using its `__file__` attribute:

   ```
   import os
   from . import __file__ as _initpy_file
   CURR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(_initpy_file))
   ```

   Actually, it doesn't have to be `__init__.py` module, you can add and import any [empty] file to make it work.

Comment: That didnt work for me, probably since I am calling `get_file()` which in turn attempts locate `__file__`. I have actually looked for a workaround. An environment variable:) in a `try-except`. But I am running into new obstacles as I try to convert .py to .pyd binaries. It looks like there are just so many things taken for granted when making .py package that doesnt hold good when converting it to .pyd

Answer (score 0):

`__file__` now works in recent more versions of Cython (0.27 ish) when on run on a version of Python that supports multi-phase module initialization (Python >=3.5). See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1715 for the point at which it was added.